# Is there some sort of CacheDependency in System.Runtime.Caching?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, .net-4.0, cache-dependency

I heard that .NET 4 has a new caching API.

Okay, so the good old `System.Web.Caching.Cache` (which is, by the way, still there in .NET 4) has the ability to set so-called `CacheDependency` objects to determine whether a cached item is expired or not.

One can also specify custom logic for determining whether a cached item is still useable or not by deriving a custom subclass from `CacheDependency`.

I'm curious, is there a way to provide such a logic in the new API?

Comment: @Steven - I mean the API provided in the System.Runtime.Caching assembly in .NET 4. (Sorry, I don't know what Velocity is.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't really used it yet but classes derived from [ChangeMonitor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.changemonitor.aspx) appear to serve a similar purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Web.Caching.Cache` with a `CacheDependency` was constructed something like the following:

```
CacheDependency cacheDependency = new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(null, new string[] { "dependentOnThisKey" });
cacheInstance.Add("someCacheKey", new object(), cacheDependency);
```

With `System.Runtime.Caching` this moves into the `CacheItemPolicy` [ChangeMonitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.changemonitor.aspx). The above example changes to the following:

```
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(MemoryCache.Default.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(new List<string> { "dependentOnThisKey" }));
cacheInstance.Add("someCacheKey", new object(), policy);
```