# .NET 4 Caching Support

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I understand the .NET 4 Framework has caching support built into it. Does anyone have any experience with this, or could provide good resources to learn more about this?

I am referring to the caching of objects (entities primarily) in memory, and probably the use of System.Runtime.Caching.

Comment: Caching of what? Are you referring to  Entity Framework, WCF or  an application server?

Comment: `System.Runtime.Caching` obviously ;-)

Comment: You should be aware of the following bug if you haven't yet upgraded to .NET 4.5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15715990/13087

Comment: [Robust .NET caching](http://www.codeducky.org/robust-net-caching/) explains how to avoid common pitfalls when caching and specifically uses [Memory Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) in the example it provides.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I assume you are getting at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx), [`System.Runtime.Caching`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx), similar to the `System.Web.Caching` and in a more general namespace.

See http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/object-caching----net-4/37

and on the stack,

[is-there-some-sort-of-cachedependency-in-system-runtime-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889812/is-there-some-sort-of-cachedependency-in-system-runtime-caching) and,

[performance-of-system-runtime-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157340/performance-of-system-runtime-caching).

Could be useful.

Answer (score 15):

I've not made use of it myself, but if you're just caching simple objects in memory, you're probably referring to the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class, in the System.Runtime.Caching namespace. There is a little example of how to use it at the end of the page.

Edit: To make it look like I've actually done some work for this answer, here's the sample from that page! :)

```
private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    string fileContents = cache["filecontents"] as string;

    if (fileContents == null)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

        List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
        filePaths.Add("c:\\cache\\example.txt");

        policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new 
        HostFileChangeMonitor(filePaths));

        // Fetch the file contents.
        fileContents = 
            File.ReadAllText("c:\\cache\\example.txt");

        cache.Set("filecontents", fileContents, policy);
    }

    Label1.Text = fileContents;
}
```

It's interesting because it shows that you can apply dependencies to the cache, much like in the classic ASP.NET cache. The big difference here is that you don't have a dependency on the System.Web assembly.

Comment: I have used this and found the documentation to be lacking.  It's my understanding that you can use it basically the same as you would System.Web caching.

Answer (score 5):

MemoryCache in the framework is a good place to start, but you might also like to consider [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache) because it has a simpler API than memory cache and has built in locking as well as some other nice features. It is available on nuget: `PM> Install-Package LazyCache`

```
// Create our cache service using the defaults (Dependency injection ready).
// Uses MemoryCache.Default as default so cache is shared between instances
IAppCache cache = new CachingService();

// Declare (but don't execute) a func/delegate whose result we want to cache
Func<ComplexObjects> complexObjectFactory = () => methodThatTakesTimeOrResources();

// Get our ComplexObjects from the cache, or build them in the factory func 
// and cache the results for next time under the given key
ComplexObject cachedResults = cache.GetOrAdd("uniqueKey", complexObjectFactory);
```

I recently wrote this article about [getting started with caching in dot net](https://alastaircrabtree.com/the-easy-way-to-add-caching-to-net-application-and-make-it-faster-is-called-lazycache/) that you may find useful.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of LazyCache)

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are referring to System.Runtime.Caching of .Netframework 4.0

Below link is the good starting point:
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN article ["ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) is a great start.