# MemoryCache empty just after adding an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm facing a strange problem with ASP.NET MemoryCaching in a MVC 3 ASP.NET application.

Each time an action is executed, I check if its LoginInfo are actually stored in the MemoryCache (code has been simplified, but core is as follow):

```
[NonAction]
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
  Boolean autorizzato = false;
  LoginInfo me = CacheUtils.GetLoginData(User.Identity.Name);
  if (me == null)
  {
    me = LoginData.UserLogin(User.Identity.Name);
    CacheUtils.SetLoginInfo(User.Identity.Name, me);
  }
  // Test if the object is really in the memory cache
  if (CacheUtils.GetLoginData(User.Identity.Name) == null) {
     throw new Exception("IMPOSSIBLE");
  } 
}
```

The GetLoginInfo is:

```
 public static LoginInfo GetLoginData(String Username)
        {
            LoginInfo local = null;
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (cache.Contains(Username.ToUpper()))
            {
                local = (LoginInfo)cache.Get(Username.ToUpper());
            }
            else
            {
                log.Warn("User " + Username + " not found  in cache");
            }
            return local;
        }
```

The SetLoginInfo is:

```
        public static void SetLoginInfo (String Username, LoginInfo Info)
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if ((Username != null) && (Info != null))
            {
                if (cache.Contains(Username.ToUpper()))
                {
                    cache.Remove(Username.ToUpper());
                }
                cache.Add(Username.ToUpper(), Info, new CacheItemPolicy());
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("NotFound...");
            }
       }
```

The code is pretty straightforward, but sometimes (totally randomly), just after adding the LoginInfo to the MemoryCache, this results empty, the just added Object is not present, therefore I got the Exception.

I'm testing this both on Cassini and IIS 7, it seems not related to AppPool reusability (enabled in IIS 7), I've tested with several Caching policies, but cannot make it work

What Am I missing/Failing ?

PS: forgive me for my bad english

Comment: Do you have a method called `GetLoginInfo` and `GetLoginData`, or is this a typo?

Comment: Have you confirmed `LoginData.UserLogin(User.Identity.Name);` isn't returning null?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: different name for setter/getter is a typo in my cut'n paste. The UserLogin method doesn't return null, it reads from a db tables user profiles, btw, cross checked with inspecting all variables. I suspect that my entry in cache is disposed by something just after I add it. WIll try to add a RemoveCallback to see if that's the case.

Comment: @BigMike, looks like `MemoryCache.Default` is process-scoped. Are you sure you're not experiencing a race condition between two threads? For instance, `Get()` could occur on thread A between `Remove()` and `Add()` on thread B.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi haven't thought about such scenario, can be a good insight. Actually the application runs in ASP.NET app pool (and if they hadn't change it, should be a thread pool of the very same IIS process). I'll investigate this tomorrow as soon as I'll be back to work. Thanks.

Comment: Also if you're low on memory or something, things could be discarded from the cache immediately?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: the whole object is a few hundreds of bytes and during tests I'm running with 10/15 fake users. Target machine is a preprod server with tons of RAM. Maybe there's some setting in .NET for defining initial space of cache ?

Comment: @BigMike Sadly, I don't really know much about the cache. I've just seen issues on one of our systems where thigns were *immediately* evicted from cache in low RAM :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into a problem that Scott Hanselman identified as a .NET 4 bug. Please see here: [MemoryCache Empty : Returns null after being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-empty-disposed-in-web-application)

Comment: Probably you're right, this question has been open for so long I almost forgot it. On our application we simply changed architecture to avoid the use of cache.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code for MemoryCache using a decomplier there is the following private function

```
private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  if (!eventArgs.IsTerminating)
    return;
  this.Dispose();
}
```

There is an unhandled exception handler setup by every MemoryCache for the current domain `Thread.GetDomain()` so if there is ever any exception in your application that is not caught which may be common in a website it disposes the MemoryCache for ever and cannot be reused this is especially relevant for IIS apps as apposed to windows applications that just exit on unhanded exceptions.

Comment: Interesting. We've removed the cache for now, as soon as we've got budget to spend on that app I will verify this.

Answer (score 2):

The *MemoryCache* has limited size. For the [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.default.aspx) instance, is't *heuristic value* (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941872.aspx)).

Have you tried to set *Priority* property on *CacheItemPolicy* instance to *NotRemovable*?

You can have race-condition because the Contains-Remove-Add sequence in *SetLoginInfo* is not atomic - try to use [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780578.aspx) method instead.

Btw. you are working on web application so why not to use [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) instead?

Comment: Hi Augi. Long time passed since I asked this, code is not up to date, I'll fix it asap. Actually we've changed our caching strategy to plain database tables. IFRC I've tried also using the Set method and the System.Web.Caching.Cache with no success.. However in the next weeks I've to work on a brand new MVC app and I'll give it a try to this. (I foresee a lot of caching but on a dedicated cache server, it'll be fun). However +1 for giving good hints. Thanks.