# Loading View with data upon reload error

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which I load with product data. When I press the 'Add to Basket' button I'd like the same page to reload again but I'm getting errors such as:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

View:

```
@model List<Ecommerce.Models.HomeModels.Product>

@foreach (Ecommerce.Models.HomeModels.Product product in Model)
{ // above error points here!!!!!!!!!!!
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {                                               
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="@product.ID" />                    
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Basket"/> 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult BuyProducts()
        {

            List<Models.HomeModels.Product> products = new List<Models.HomeModels.Product>();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   //Method to load data into products
                }
            }

            TempData["products"] = products; 

            return View(products);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult BuyProducts(string productID)
        {
            string id = productID;
            return View(TempData["products"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TempData` only exists for one request, so it is gone by the time you try to send it back (Which is why you get the error - `TempData["products"]` is `null`). Either way, you should use the post redirect get pattern, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult BuyProducts(string productID)
{
    string id = productID;
    return RedirectToAction("BuyProducts");
}
```

The main reason is that if the user refreshes the page and you returned a view from post, the data will be posted a second time causing duplication.

Comment: This actually would be the correct way to go about it for the reason he stated. You could cache the products list somewhere so your not calling the database every time on the redirect, but that's a separate topic.

Comment: How would I go about caching it? Or could you please redirect me to some resources?

Comment: @Neeta - Darin is a good resource for asp.net mvc 3, you should browse some of his answers because he puts out a lot of good content. Here is one of his answers on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8485517/1026459

Answer (score 1):

`TempData` isn't persisted across requests. You can either use `Session` or `ViewData` to save `"products"`

Try one of those and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks for that information as it's very useful. Was actually hoping for something simpler though.