# How do I detect at runtime that .NET version 4.5 is currently running your code?

Tags: .net, clr, version, .net-4.5

I installed .NET 4.5 Developer preview from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27541, which 'replaces' .NET 4.0 version.

However, the old way to detect the .NET framework version seems to return 4.0 (more precisely 4.0.30319.17020 on my PC), instead of 4.5 (sure probably for backward compatibility, or?):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var version = Environment.Version;
            Console.WriteLine(version.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I detect that my code is really executed by .NET 4.5?

Comment: When you install .NET it doesn't 'replace' anything. Go look in `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and you'll see a folder for each framework you have installed. If you want to change the framework under which your application is compiled, just open the properties of your Project in Solution Explorer, and then select the correct framework from the "Target Framework" dropdown.

Comment: There is no "CLR 4.5", it still uses CLR version 4.0.30319.

Comment: @tobias86: .NET 4.5 is different. It REPLACES .NET 4.0 on your PC! :)

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, true, I mean here .NET 4.5, thanks :) Fixed

Comment: Well, connect the dots, the last sentence of your question is thus unanswerable.  Only logical thing to do is check if 4.5 is installed.  If it is then there's no way that the 4.0 revision is executing your program.

Comment: Why in the world do you *care* about the version of the runtime environment? It sounds to me like you're trying to solve a problem the wrong way round.

Comment: HansPassant, CodyGray: let's just assume, I install .NET 4.5 and now confused is it really work or something was wrong during installation and I still use .NET 4.0 (for both Windows apps and especially ASP.NET MVC hosts). I do NOT want to do benchmarks of GC or to use "features detection" (see answer from Christian.K) to know what runtime execute my code. Great deal of improvements / new features introduced by .NET 4.5 and it looks confusing for me that there is no way how to detect that code executed by it (not to detect that v4.5 installed, which is trivial, but that it actually WORKS!).

Comment: Btw, I use also following "checks": `var version = typeof(int).Assembly.GetName().Version; var version2 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion();  var version3 = typeof(int).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;` - same result, i.e. 4.0.0.0 or 4.0.30319 everywhere :)

Comment: @EvereQ Sorry to say that, but from the wording of your latest comment above, you still don't seem to grasp the difference between .NET as a whole (package), the CLR and/or the framework libraries. Anyway, I've added some more information to my answer on why I think what you ask for is arguably not even possible or wanted.

Comment: @Christian.K I would not made such assumptions about me, however thanks that you update your answer. To show you how wrong you can be with me and with .NET 4.5 in general, please answer following: What you think, GC is part of CLR or not? Now read for example: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/09/17/improvements-in-the-clr-core-in-net-framework-4-5.aspx See how many improvements was done in .NET 4.5 GC? So it IS important in SOME scenarios to detect which runtime execute your code and it have nothing to do with differences between .NET as whole, CLR and framework libs :)

Comment: @EverQ I was not trying to put words in your mouth or make any assumptions (hence me saying "you still don't _seem_..."). If you have taken any offense, sorry about that. Anyway, concerning your example, you *can* figure that the new CLR (that which apparently is still v4.0 even it ships with .NET 4.5). Examples given below.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to make a clear distinction between the CLR (i.e. the "runtime") and the framework libraries (i.e. the "framework"). You execute your code on or with the first, your code is compiled against and uses the later. Unfortunately when using the the term ".NET *version*" one is usually referring to the whole package of both runtime and framework, regardless of their individual versions which - as has been said - can differ.

You can detect the [installed framework versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785). That doesn't, however, tell you which one you are actually using at runtime.

I'm not sure about 4.5, but with 2.0 vs. 3.0 or 3.5 `Environment.Version` was of no help since it always returned 2.0 as all those framework versions were using the CLR 2.0. I *presume* that with the **framework** 4.5 the CLR version is still 4.0, which would explain that `Environment.Version` returns 4.0.x even in that case.

A technique that may work for you is to check for a type, method or property in the core libraries (mscorlib, System.Core, etc.) that you'd know only existed starting with a particular .NET framework version.

For example, the [ReflectionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectioncontext(v=vs.110).aspx) class seems to be totally new with the .NET framework 4.5 and conveniently lives in `mscorlib`. So you could do something like this.

```
  public static bool IsNet45OrNewer()
  {
      // Class "ReflectionContext" exists from .NET 4.5 onwards.
      return Type.GetType("System.Reflection.ReflectionContext", false) != null;
  }
```

Having all that said, one could question why you need to know which .NET version you are using. Simply try to access the features you require and possibly gracefully fallback to something else (that was available in older versions) if they are not present.

**Update**: Note that the term .NET 4.5 refers to the whole package of several assemblies that make up the base class libraries (BCL) and more (collectively called "framework") plus the runtime itself, i.e. the CLR - both of which can have different versions, as has been said.

I don't work for Microsoft and have no insight into the real reasons behind the lack of a (single) function or API to get "the .NET framework version", but I can make an educated guess.

1. **It is not clear what information in particular such a function/API should provide.** Even the individual assemblies of the BCL don't share a common (assembly/file) version. For example, with .NET 3.0 and 3.5, the mscorlib.dll had version 2.0.x while only the new assemblies of WCF and WF had 3.0 something. I *think* even with .NET 3.5 the `System.ServiceModel.dll` still had version 3.0.x. What I'm trying to say, there is no unified version on all assemblies of the framework. So what should an API call like, say, `System.Environment.FrameworkVersion`return? What value would the version be (even if it did return the "symbolic" version like 4.5, it would be of little value, wouldn't it?).
2. **Too specific** Some new features might arrive in SPs to existing versions, plus being part of a new version. Doing feature checking, your application might run perfectly well on *previous* versions, that have been updated, while with explicit version checking it might unneccessarily restrict itself to the newest version. I don't have an example from the .NET world for this, but in general (and in Windows itself, e.g. WMI) it can and did happen.
3. **Not wanted.** I could imagine that a method to figure "the version of the framework" that is currently being used by an application is not even *desirable* for them to provide. There is a long and unholy history of [version checking fallacies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/01/14/common-problems-with-checking-os-versions-in-code.aspx) (see "Don't Check Version" paragraph for concepts that apply to .NET as well), in the native/Win32 world. For example, people used the `GetVersion` and `GetVersionEx` APIs wrong, by only checking that they run the version they knew was the newest when they wrote their application. So, when the application was run on a newer version of windows, it wouldn't run, even though the *features* they really were using are still there. Microsoft might have considered issues like that and thus not even provided some API in .NET.

Incidentally this is what Microsoft [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the remarks section of the GetVersion function:

> Identifying the current operating system is usually not the best way
>   to determine whether a particular operating system feature is present.
>   This is because the operating system may have had new features added
>   in a redistributable DLL. Rather than using GetVersionEx to determine
>   the operating system platform or version number, test for the presence
>   of the feature itself.

The Windows Team Blog also has something [to say](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/05/version-checking-just-don-t-do-it.aspx) about this.

I know all this was about Windows and native programming, but the concept and dangers are the same for .NET applications the framework and the CLR.

I would say feature checking with (graceful) fallback is thus a much more reliable and robust way to make sure your application is downwards compatible. If you only want your application to work with a specific version of .NET or newer, don't do anything special at all and count on the backwards compatibility of .NET itself.

Comment: sure, thanks for answer! I was think about "modernizr" approach too :), however JavaScript way to detect features is not common way to do such things in .NET :) If continue your answer, probably next thing in addition to "gracefully fallback", will be to use some "polyfill" to substitute .NET 4.5 features :D etc. I just think that MSFT should have some other way to detect which runtime version execute code :)

Comment: I would recommend everybody also to read following blog post by Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx. Especially I like the idea to add <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />  into app.config for almost any app type, EXCEPT ASP.NET if your app require .NET 4.5 runtime. (user will be promoted to install .NET 4.5 if it's not available). It's not exactly detection, however :(... Anyway, my +1 to ask ASP.NET team if they can add support for such configuration parameter too.

Comment: just want to add my reason to check if .net 4.5 framework is installed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15715990/423356 (the MemoryCache.Default get disposed on web application bug)

Comment: @kite yes, it's exactly that case, when you can detect the .NET version and apply some workaround if required :) Good point, thanks. Again however, think it should be more easy to detect .NET version than what is selected now as right answer here... Especially for situations when such detection should be fast enough (solution above uses reflection so better to make sure you store IsNet45OrNewer in some static property after first detection and use that instead of calling method with reflection inside).

Comment: i.e. for cases where performance matters, something like that will work a bit better:  
    `public static class TypeExtensions
    {

        private static readonly bool IsNet45OrNewerDetected;

        static TypeExtensions()
        {
            IsNet45OrNewerDetected = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.ReflectionContext", false) != null;
        }

        public static bool IsNet45OrNewer()
        {
            // Class "ReflectionContext" exists from .NET 4.5 onwards.
            return IsNet45OrNewerDetected;
        }

    }`

Comment: **UPDATE .NET 4.5.1**: if you need check for latest .NET Framework version 4.5.1, feel free to use another type (enum) that was introduced in that version: **System.Runtime.GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode**, e.g.: `Type.GetType("System.Runtime.GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode", false) != null`

Comment: MS have a new article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx that shows how to get installed .NET versions using regedit (interactive use) or C# code.

Comment: A slightly better check will be to look up the `ReflectionContext` in the mscorlib.dll itself in case someone has created this type in their own assembly: `typeof(string).Assembly.GetType("System.Reflection.ReflectionContext", false) != null`

Answer (score 32):

To determine exactly which patch of .NET your application is running, make this call to find the build number of mscorlib:

```
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(int).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
```

It currently returns 4.6.1055.0 for me, which corresponds to .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: Nice metho and trivially easy to implement. But is there a list of possible values of this value, so that we can match a version number to a particular framework?

Comment: @Alejandro I'm not aware of one.  However, you probably shouldn't try to work backwards from this number because multiple patches will exist for the same 'marketing' version of the framework.

Comment: @JamesL Sure, but that can be easily considered by performing range comparisons against the expected version numbers, covering for all possible patches for each major version. So far this method is the only way I could find to get the exact runtime actually executing.

Comment: Thank you for this. Your answer is underrated given the lack of any other reliable way of finding the runtime. Given the recent drop in quality of framework releases, this is getting more and more important to tell when trying to diagnose obscure client side bugs.

Comment: Dammit!  Looks lovely, but throws a System.Security.SecurityException in the hosted environment I needed to know about. :(

Comment: Using reflector i see that .Net ThreadExceptionDialog uses FileVersion, but is seems FileVersion and ProductVersion is the same for mscorlib anyways thou (this is what is showing as Win32 Version:)

Answer (score 25):

The .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to 4.0. This loosely means that if you are running on a version 4.0 or 4.5 runtime, and 4.5 is installed, then you are certainly running on 4.5. Your check might go as follows.

Let's call both the 4.0 and 4.5 runtimes ***4.0-versioned runtimes***.

1. Check whether you are running on a 4.0-versioned runtime:

   - If your assembly is compiled to target .NET 4.0, or
   - `Environment.Version.Major == 4 && Environment.Version.Minor == 0`

   then you are running on a 4.0-versioned runtime.
2. Check whether your 4.0-versioned runtime is actually version 4.0 or 4.5, by checking the installed version:

   - Under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client`, check the `_Version_` value. If it starts with `"4.0"` you are running on the 4.0 runtime, if it starts with `"4.5"` you are running on the 4.5 runtime.

Answer (score 8):

James provides the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35889259/147511) of fetching the "product version" of **mscorlib.dll** at runtime:

(`using System.Diagnostics;`)

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(int).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
```

This works well, but you can get a more fine-grained result by examining **System.dll** instead:

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
```

Notice the slight difference is to use the assembly for `typeof(Uri)` instead of `typeof(int)`, since the former is defined in `System.dll` as opposed to `mscorlib.dll` for the latter. For a simple C# console program targeting **.NET 4.7.1**, the difference, as currently reported on my system, is as follows**:**

> ...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll   4.7.**2600**.0
>   ...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll    4.7.**2556**.0

As for whether the distinction is useful or how to use the more detailed information, that will depend on the particular situation.

Answer (score 5):

You can test whether the **.NET Framework 4.5** or the **.NET Framework 4** is installed by checking the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full` subkey in the registry for a `DWORD` value named `Release`. The existence of this `DWORD` indicates that the **.NET Framework 4.5** has been installed on that computer. The value of `Release` is a version number. To determine if the final release version of the **.NET Framework 4.5** is installed, check for a value that is equal to or greater than `378389`.

Comment: The registry key and the IsNet45OrNewer() function from Christian.K are perfect.  Thanks, @Vipul!

Comment: From MSDN about this registry value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx '''You must have administrative credentials to run this example'''

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood from online resources, .NET 4.5 will act in a similar way (although not completely the same) as 3.5 did for 2.0: your version number remains the same (if you run 3.5 code the CLR version will be 2.0), and it will act as an update of the existing CLR 4.0.

So you'll be able to have coexisting 2.0 upgraded to 3.5 and 4.0 upgraded to 4.5.

What remains unclear is if it will be possible to make (or work on existing) projects in 4.0 without having to upgrade them to 4.5: currently you can make 2.0 or 3.5 projects in Visual Studio 2010, but maybe it won't be the same for 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: You just compile your project for .NET 4.0 and it automatically runs under .NET 4.5 as far as I understand (sure if on your PC you have .NET 4.5 installed). However it's still unclear how to detect that in Runtime!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with .NET Core 3.0 (and .NET Standard 2.1) situation is changed and now `Environment.Version` working properly. So you can use this property to detect dot net version you using.

```cs
System.Console.WriteLine($"Environment.Version: {System.Environment.Version}");

// Old result
//   Environment.Version: 4.0.30319.42000
//
// New result
//   Environment.Version: 3.0.0
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#improved-net-core-version-apis) for further information.