# How to get the .NET framework version that the application is using

Tags: c#

I have referred to the Stack Overflow question *[Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856)*. But the suggestions given there did not work for the following purpose.

How can we identify the .NET version that the C# console application is using?

**Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET Framework: 3.5 (please see attached screenshot)

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace TESTConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //.NET version: Approach 1
            RegistryKey installed_versions = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP");
            string[] version_names = installed_versions.GetSubKeyNames();
            double latestFramework = Convert.ToDouble(version_names[version_names.Length - 1].Remove(0, 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            int SP = Convert.ToInt32(installed_versions.OpenSubKey(version_names[version_names.Length - 1]).GetValue("SP", 0));
            Console.WriteLine(latestFramework);

            //Approach 2
            string versionval = Environment.Version.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(versionval);

            //Approach 3
            string systemVersionVal = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(systemVersionVal);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**VERSION Setup**

[image]

Comment: @Habib sorry abt that

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8543850/284111 ?

Comment: You need to be more specific what "version" you need - with building for 3.5 you get runtime 2.0 OR 4.0. It maybe what you need, but clarification will help.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd and 3rd approached are the `CLR version numbers`.

.NET Framework 2 and .NET Framework 3.5 are using `CLR 2.0`.

And there's no CLR 3.0 or 3.5.

Comment: This...unless you're loading WCF libs, then I'm not sure what it would say...