# How to check programmatically if .NET 4.7 Target Pack is installed?

Tags: .net, frameworks

Whe have found a way to check, if MsBuild.exe is installed, but we also need to know if the [targeting pack for .NET 4.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=55168) ist already installed or not. Visual Studio is not installed, only the Framework 4.7 and maybe the targeting pack ...

Does anyone know how to check it?

Comment: visual studio installer >> components installed

Comment: I edited the question a bit ...

Comment: I would check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517159/how-do-i-detect-at-runtime-that-net-version-4-5-is-currently-running-your-code/13764601#13764601

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that you can see in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\` which targeting packs are installed. For each pack there will be a folder with its version number, for example

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\4.7
```

[more information here](https://n3wjack.net/2017/07/23/fixing-msb3644-build-errors-and-the-point-of-net-targeting-packs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tools like [RegMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/regmon) and reverse engineer the process to find related registry keys.

Use a [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), run registry monitoring tool and install developer pack. After installation check for registry changes specially under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP` path.

Comment: that's not easy, there happens a lot

Comment: Yes. Another solution is checking `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry path for installed apps. Your solution may not work on 64-bit machine.

Comment: even on 64-bit CPU and 64-bit Windows the folders are in Program Files (x86), I tried it out ...