# MemoryCache does not work after several minutes

Tags: c#, memorycache

Here is my code:

```
public class ConfigCache
{
    private static volatile ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private const string KeyModule = "MODULE_XDOC_KEY";
    private static string _settingFile;

    public ConfigCache(string file)
    {
        _settingFile = file;
    }

    public XDocument Get()
    {
        var doc = _cache[KeyModule] as XDocument;
        if (doc == null)
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(_settingFile);
            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            var filePaths = new List<string> {_settingFile};
            policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HostFileChangeMonitor(filePaths));
            var callback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(this.MyCachedItemRemovedCallback);
            policy.RemovedCallback = callback;
            _cache.Set(KeyModule, doc, policy);
        }

        return _cache[KeyModule] as XDocument;
    }

    private void MyCachedItemRemovedCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        // Log these values from arguments list 
    }
}
```

When run into _cache.Set() first time, it works fine:

- _cache.Set() works well, it add the xdoc into cache.

But after several minutes(1 or 2 minutes), cache will not work anymore:

- _cache.Set() does not insert anything into cache
- _cache.Set() does not report any error.
- the callback MyCachedItemRemovedCallback never triggered.

Someone met same issue: 
[MemoryCache always returns "null" after first expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254708/memorycache-always-returns-null-after-first-expiration)

But it seems not resolved yet. Anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Can you explain the host process? Is it running as a web application hosted in IIS, or is it a windows service?

Comment: The host process is a web application in IIS 7, OS is win 7

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that the cache is being disposed. This will result in the `MemoryCache` silently returning `null` rather than throwing any exception. First search your code to be sure you are not disposing it. If you are sure you aren't disposing it, try breaking on the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event. `MemoryCache` subscribes to this event (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-disposed-in-web-application/15203581#15203581) and disposes itself. If you are handling the `UnhandledException` event in your app as a global error handler, this could be the problem.

If this is the issue, a simple workaround is to handle the event and recreate a new instance of the cache. (See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281603/1445661))