# Azure app service availability loss. The memory counter Page Reads/sec was at a dangerous level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, out-of-memory, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

Environment:
Asp Net MVC app(.net framework 4.5.1) hosted on Azure app service with two instances.
App uses Azure SQL server database.
Also, app uses MemoryCache (System.Runtime.Caching) for caching purposes.

Recently, I noticed availability loss of the app. It happens almost every day.
[image]

[image]
Observations:
The memory counter Page Reads/sec was at a dangerous level (242) on instance RD0003FF1F6B1B. Any value over 200 can cause delays or failures for any app on that instance.

What 'The memory counter Page Reads/sec' means?
How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrGorodytskyi, we seem to meet more often - I just recently had the same problem again - app out for half an hour while seemingly not any more traffic or anything unusual. Any tips that you can share with above problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What 'The memory counter Page Reads/sec' means?

We could get the answer from this [blog](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-memory-performance-metrics-part-3-sql-server-buffer-manager-metrics-memory-counters/). The recommended Page reads/sec value should be under **90**. Higher values indicate **insufficient memory** and **indexing issues**.

> “Page reads/sec indicates the number of physical database page reads that are issued per second. This statistic displays the total number of physical page reads across all databases. Because physical I/O is expensive, you may be able to minimize the cost, either by using a larger data cache, intelligent indexes, and more efficient queries, or by changing the database design.”

---

> How to fix this issue?

Based on my experience, you could have a try to [enable Local Cache in App
Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview#enable-local-cache-in-app-service).

> You enable Local Cache on a per-web-app basis by using this app setting: **WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Always**
>
> By default, the local cache size is **300 MB**. This includes the /site and /siteextensions folders that are copied from the content store, as well as any locally created logs and data folders. To increase this limit, use the app setting **WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SIZEINMB**. You can increase the size up to **2 GB (2000 MB)** per web app.

Comment: Is it free feature?

Comment: Yes, it is free feature.  As WebApp is paid by [service plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I enabled local cache. Hope it will help!

Comment: @VolodymyrGorodytskyi How did it go? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: What has this do to with databases? My Web App is failing while the database doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: also don't get the link with WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE (despite it being good advice in general)

Comment: But this is an issue with page faults, how is related with the web content (files inside D:/home/site/...) local cache works with those files, having high page reads/secs means that we have a bad memory management, my problem is i have sufficient memory and i still getting high page reads, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is some memory performance problems can be listed

- excessive paging,
- memory shortages,
- memory leaks

Memory counter values can be used to detect the presence of various performance problems. Tracking counter values both on a **system-wide** and a **per-process** basis helps you to pinpoint the cause in Azure such as in other systems.

Even if there is no change in the process, a change in the system can cause memory problems. the **system-wide**

**researching in the azure**:

Shared resources plans (Free and Basic) have memory limits as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits.

**Quotas**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor

Also, you can check in the portal under your web app settings, search for “quotas”, and also check out “Diagnose and solve problems” and hit “metrics per instance (app service plan)” which will show you memory used for the plan.

A MemoryCache bug in .net 4 can also cause this type of behavior
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715990/914284