# Where to find System.Runtime.Caching to reference in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm writing a fairly simple Windows Forms tool to help me perform some things on a database. I frequently need to go to the database to get IDs and I can't do away with getting the IDs.

I found some references to it such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978482/net-4-caching-support), which all suggest I should be looking for System.Runtime.Caching, but when I go to Add Reference, There are no System.Runtime.Caching components.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your project set to use full .NET 4.0, or is it configured for just .NET 4.0 Client Profile?

Comment: Since my answer to your question is "I don't know", then the answer is probably .NET 4.0 Client.  How would I check this, and could I possibly change it?

Comment: Right click on your project inside Visual Studio, and see the highlight here: http://i.imgur.com/WJpUh.png

Comment: Perfect! you should submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The project is configured for .NET 4.0 Client Profile, which is a reduced subset of assemblies/features. It's designed for "client apps", where you don't need ASP.NET and backend functionality. It's supposed to lead to faster installs and deployments.

You can change the target framework by right clicking on your project in Visual Studio, and under the Applications tab, change the target to the full .NET 4.0 Framework. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beNVg.png) for a screenshot of what to change.