# Built-in Cache Interface in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, caching, interface

I had read somewhere when reading up on AppFabric Caching that there was a built-in cache Interface in .NET. Now I can't seem to locate it. Need interface to limit interactions to Get and Put calls.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978482/net-4-caching-support

Comment: I followed the link and there is no specific mention of an Interface. I was looking for an ICache ? System.Runtime.Caching does not seem to have any types in it that start with a capital I.