# How do I clear a System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, .net-4.0

I use a `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` to hold items which never expire. However, at times I need the ability to clear the entire cache. How do I do that?

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023543/can-i-iterate-over-the-net4-memorycache/) concerning whether I could enumerate the cache, but that is a bad idea as it needs to be synchronised during enumeration.

I've tried using `.Trim(100)` but that doesn't work at all.

I've tried getting a list of all the keys via Linq, but then I'm back where I started because evicting items one-by-one can easily lead to race conditions.

I thought to store all the keys, and then issue a `.Remove(key)` for each one, but there is an implied race condition there too, so I'd need to lock access to the list of keys, and things get messy again.

I then thought that I should be able to call `.Dispose()` on the entire cache, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach, due to the way it's implemented.

Using `ChangeMonitors` is not an option for my design, and is unnecassarily complex for such a trivial requirement.

So, how do I completely clear the cache?

Comment: MSDN explicitly states that it is *not* a singleton: "Another difference is that you can create multiple instances of the MemoryCache class for use in the same application and in the same AppDomain instance."

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah! I was probably looking at the wrong documentation. So that would seem to imply that I can call ``.Dispose()``, and then when I call ``MemoryCache.Default``, I'll get a brand-spanking new instance...

Comment: is simply swapping to a new instance and disposing the old a problem? assuming synced, etc

Comment: no if you call dispose on the default instance, you've killed the default instance. So... don't use `.Default` if you are planning on using Dispose! That doesn't make it a singleton, though...

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183270/how-to-clear-the-net-4-memorycache) which I only found now. But the discussion surrounding ``Dispose()`` is incomplete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should not call dispose on the Default member of the MemoryCache if you want to be able to use it anymore:

> The state of the cache is set to indicate that the cache is disposed.
>   Any attempt to call public caching methods that change the state of
>   the cache, such as methods that add, remove, or retrieve cache
>   entries, might cause unexpected behavior. For example, if you call the
>   Set method after the cache is disposed, a no-op error occurs. If you
>   attempt to retrieve items from the cache, the Get method will always
>   return Nothing.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.dispose.aspx

About the Trim, it's supposed to work:

> The Trim property first removes entries that have exceeded either an absolute or sliding expiration. Any callbacks that are registered
>   for items that are removed will be passed a removed reason of Expired.
>
> If removing expired entries is insufficient to reach the specified trim percentage, additional entries will be removed from the cache
>   based on a least-recently used (LRU) algorithm until the requested
>   trim percentage is reached.

But two other users reported it doesnt work on same page so I guess you are stuck with Remove() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.trim.aspx

*Update*
However I see no mention of it being singleton or otherwise unsafe to have multiple instances so you should be able to overwrite your reference.

But if you need to free the memory from the Default instance you will have to clear it manually or destroy it permanently via dispose (rendering it unusable).

Based on your question you could make your own singleton-imposing class returning a Memorycache you may internally dispose at will.. Being the nature of a cache :-)

Comment: So I could wrap an instance that I create--i.e. not the Default instance--in an adapter class, which is a singleton. Then when I want to clear the contained cache, I just create a new one, and whip the GC.

Comment: @Peter Marks I see no reason why it would fail on you. And Dispose() should really do the trick in general but if its alot of data calling GC.Collect() may be a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Trim(100)` does not always evict 100% of the items in the cache:

https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback/details/831755/memorycache-trim-method-doesnt-evict-100-of-the-items

Comment: I had no luck with Trim either so here is an example how you could use remove: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334092/1641941

Comment: Clean build process will clear the cache for local iis or iis express? And for hosted sites that are not on local iis what is the life time of cache? Is it forever until app pool recycled?

Answer (score 37):

I was struggling with this at first. MemoryCache.Default.Trim(100) does not work (as discussed). Trim is a best attempt, so if there are 100 items in the cache, and you call Trim(100) it will remove the ones least used.

Trim returns the count of items removed, and most people expect that to remove all items.

This code removes all items from MemoryCache for me in my xUnit tests with MemoryCache.Default. MemoryCache.Default is the default Region.

```
foreach (var element in MemoryCache.Default)
{
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(element.Key);
}
```

Comment: To be clear, Trim takes a *percentage*, not an absolute count, so Trim(100) is indicating that 100% of the items -- not 100 items -- should be removed.

Comment: You should definitely add thread-synchronization here. Surprised you're not getting the "modifying this collection while enumerating" exception.

Comment: This usage shouldn't raise an `IllegalOperationException` due to how [MemoryCache implements `GetEnumerator()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs,d4a8840a7c5b83b9).  It creates a new `Dictionary<string, object>` by copying data from it's internal storage and returns an enumerator for that new object, so the MemoryCache itself is not being enumerated and modified at the same time.

Comment: I use this approach in my TestInitialize for unit tests. I recommend to avoid this in production code!

Comment: MS docs state this: "Retrieving an enumerator for a MemoryCache instance is a resource-intensive and blocking operation. Therefore, the enumerator should not be used in production applications."

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question but the best option I've come across is to

> Dispose the existing MemoryCache and create a new MemoryCache object.
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183319/880642

The answer doesn't really provide the code to do this in a thread safe way. But this can be achieved using [Interlocked.Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var oldCache = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _existingCache, new MemoryCache("newCacheName"));
oldCache.Dispose();
```

This will swap the existing cache with a new one and allow you to safely call Dispose on the original cache. This avoids needing to enumerate the items in the cache and race conditions caused by disposing a cache while it is in use.

---

**Edit**

Here's how I use it in practice accounting for DI

```
public class CustomCacheProvider : ICustomCacheProvider
{
    private IMemoryCache _internalCache;
    private readonly ICacheFactory _cacheFactory;

    public CustomCacheProvider (ICacheFactory cacheFactory)
    {
        _cacheFactory = cacheFactory;
        _internalCache = _cacheFactory.CreateInstance();
    }
    public void Set(string key, object item, MemoryCacheEntryOptions policy)
    {
        _internalCache.Set(key, item, policy);
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        return _internalCache.Get(key);
    }
   // other methods ignored for breviy 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _internalCache?.Dispose();
    }

    public void EmptyCache()
    {
        var oldCache = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _internalCache, _cacheFactory.CreateInstance());
        oldCache.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The key is controlling access to the internal cache using another singleton which has the ability to create new cache instances using a factory (or manually if you prefer).

Comment: The exchange is not enough IMO: how are concurrent readers protected from the dispose? I think you need a "multiple reads single write" lock to be really safe.

Comment: If I inject the cache with DI as a singleton I don't understand how to run this code. Disposing of the MemoryCache works but assigning the new value in is hard since _existingCache must be a ref, which means it can't be a property, which means it can't be the private property I assigned the injected MemoryCache to when I injected it. Is there a way around this which lets me modify the object which is injected into the class? (I know this is a DI question; I just don't know how to solve it and if there's a better general question here)

Comment: @GregoryLedray Updated the answer with some sample code that uses DI to provide a potential way to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Here's is what I had made for something I was working on...

```
public void Flush()
{
    List<string> cacheKeys = MemoryCache.Default.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
    foreach (string cacheKey in cacheKeys)
    {
        MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The details in @stefan's answer detail the principle; here's how I'd do it.

One should synchronise access to the cache whilst recreating it, to avoid the race condition of client code accessing the cache after it is disposed, but before it is recreated.

To avoid this synchronisation, do this in your adapter class (which wraps the MemoryCache):

```
public void clearCache() {
  var oldCache = TheCache;
  TheCache = new MemoryCache("NewCacheName", ...);
  oldCache.Dispose();
  GC.Collect();
}
```

This way, `TheCache` is always in a non-disposed state, and no synchronisation is needed.

Comment: really? a full blown GC.Collect?

Comment: This solution definitely DOES NOT avoid the stated race condition. Consider thread A gets a reference to `TheCache` and starts doing operations on it. Thread B calls `clearCache`, which runs to completion. Thread A is still running, but its using the disposed cache.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. .Dispose() did something quite different than what I expected.

Instead, I added a static field to my controller class. I did not use the default cache, to get around this behavior, but created a private one (if you want to call it that). So my implementation looked a bit like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    static MemoryCache s_cache = new MemoryCache("myCache");

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (conditionThatInvalidatesCache)
        {
            s_cache = new MemoryCache("myCache");
        }

        String s = s_cache["key"] as String;

        if (s == null)
        {
            //do work
            //add to s_cache["key"]
        }

        //do whatever next
    }
}
```

Comment: MemoryCache implements IDisposable so you should call Dispose before replacing the old instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183270/how-to-clear-the-net-4-memorycache/22388943#comment34789210_22388943) post, and specifically, the answer that [Thomas F. Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549587/thomas-f-abraham) posted. 
It has a solution that enables you to clear the entire cache or a named subset.

The key thing here is:

```
// Cache objects are obligated to remove entry upon change notification.
base.OnChanged(null);
```

I've implemented this myself, and everything seems to work just fine.